# Multiple WordPress posts in different sections

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress website where the front page has multiple blog posts on it, but all with a (slightly) different HTML and also on different places, so just making the loop repeat itself won't do the job.

**Design preview:**

[image]

I was thinking I could maybe make a query for every post and then use 'offset 1', 'offset 2', etc. to query in the right order.

And then after each query reset post data.

Would this be a good method or is this too much load? Any other good solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. It will first of all check if there are more posts before it tries to load it. And if there is, you just will get the next story in line to get printed. Just use the `if( more_posts() )` where you need to insert a post in your layout

```
function more_posts() {
     global $wp_query;
     return $wp_query->current_post + 1 < $wp_query->post_count;
}
if( more_posts() ){
    the_post();
    the_title();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out. I just came across this one as well, do you think both have similar load on the site? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196149/how-to-add-div-blocks-after-certain-set-of-post

Comment: There will be slim to none noticable difference in loading time using a while loop or doing it like the way above. Its the `the_post()` command that loads the next post in line from the database that puts down any performance demanding operation (not that this costs to much either)